# Compare strings as numbers in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, comparison, coercion

I have the following query in SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY t1.field
```

Where `t1.field` is a text column containing numbers. Is it posible to force SQLite to consider the values of t1.field as numbers instead of strings (whithout doing `ALTER TABLE`)? Right now the sort is a pure string one, so 10 goes before 2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, found a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY t1.field + 0
```

The `+ 0` part seems to force conversion to number

Comment: thank you this helped me, out of interest on what platform were you using SQLite on?

Comment: SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY CAST(t1.field AS INTEGER)

Comment: You can even sort mixed data. If using `ORDER BY t1.field + 0, t1.field`, this will first sort all numbers, then all strings that could not be converted to a number -> `["no", "yes", "1", "5", "10", 50"]`

Comment: It will even order mixed strings: `["10 dogs", "2 dogs", "35 dogs"]` becomes `["2 dogs", "10 dogs", "35 dogs"]`