# Order a column with integers numerical when retrieving data as strings using sqlite database in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I've got a sqlite table with sub_id's, these are stored as strings. When I order with this column, I get my data ordered like this:

1, 10, 13, 16, 2, 23, etc

How can I order them numerically?

My code:

```
var id = Expression<Int>("id")
let m_id = Expression<String>("m_id")

let chapters = try self.database.prepare(self.chaptersTable.order(self.m_id))

for chapter in chapters {
    print("chapter Id: \(chapter[self.m_id])")
    idsChapters.append(chapter[self.id])
    mIdChapters.append(chapter[self.m_id])
}
```

I can't use change may database format due to Android compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this at the moment, but try:

```
let chapters = try self.database.prepare(self.chaptersTable.order(CAST(self.m_id AS INTEGER)))
```

Gleaned from the SO question [Compare strings as numbers in SQLite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204319/compare-strings-as-numbers-in-sqlite3), comment by @Martin Ždila